# Datepicker not showing to Dynamically created rows using TemplateBuilder

Tags: java, jquery, html, datepicker

I'm stuck at a part in my code where I'm trying to generate a Dynamic Row using TemplateBulider having one of it's fields as a date picker.

The part in TemplateBuilder for which the datapicker filed is displayed:

```
<link href="/assets/bootstrap_assets/xeditable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/bootstrap_assets/xeditable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js"></script>

<tr>

    <td>{BlockId}</td>
    <td> <input type="text" placeholder="click to show datepicker"  id="EstStartDt_{BlockId}" class="form-control input-sm" value=""/> </td>

</tr>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // When the document is ready
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#EstStartDt_{BlockId}.").datepicker({
            format: "mm/dd/yyyy"
        });  
    });
</script>
```

My output run is able to capture datepicker id with the values from the database (on firebug inspection console : Eg for a particular run : The ID of datepicker is assigned as EstStartDt_1142 ), as expected but the datepicker is not showing on click.

Comment: Use Class selectors and apply datepicker like this - $(".form-control input-sm").datepicker({
            format: "mm/dd/yyyy"
        });

Comment: Thanks for ur response. Tried this option. Still the same. The datepicker is not triggered.  <script type="text/javascript">
  
  $(document).ready(function () {
   $(".form-control input-sm").datepicker({ format: "mm/dd/yyyy" }); 
   });  
  });
 </script>

Answer (score 1):

This finally worked for me. I have added it in my main script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('body').on('focus',".datepick", function(){
        $(this).datepicker();
    });
</script>
```